# Bootstrap 5 tooltip placement top issue when page has a scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with tooltips in bootstrap when the placement top is forced. I use the latest version for now: 5.1.3

I have tried to create a code snipped, but the issue is not reproducible on codepen, so I will paste a code here with a video sample.

```js
function initTooltips() {
  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  tooltipTriggerList.forEach(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  });
}

initTooltips();
```

```css
.section {
  padding-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center mt-5 pt-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="test-btn" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip with button">
                Tooltip on top
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll the page a bit down to see see the button and hover the mouse over it, the tooltip appears on top with a gap equal to the scroll position.

[image: Video sample of the problem]

I tried to play with tooltip options like "boundary" and "container" but it does not help much.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, I can't reproduce your issue. Maybe you have more code that you are not showing us?

Comment: @cloned, thank you for your reply and the time you spent for creating a code snippet. The problem is not reproducible in an iframe, probably the issue inside popper.js. As was mentioned in a question description, I have tried to create a snippet and could not reproduce the issue that way. So I created a minimal HTML code, that can be easily copied and pasted to a local HTML file for testing. I think it is much better to revert the question description to the original state, otherwise, nobody will understand the problem. what do you think?

Comment: If it can be reproduced locally it can be reproduced in an iframe. Maybe you need some additional css? Or tell users to view this in full screen?

Comment: it can be reproduced, but the question does not make sense after your formating. Please, do not reformat the questions without confirmation from the owner in the future

Comment: All I did was put your code in a snippet. Feel free to modify the snippet so we can see your problem, I don't see where I missed something from your code? Sorry if I did miss something from your code. Please update the snippet with your code so we can reproduce your issue there :)

Comment: See my answer below. when you create a snipped, the rendering system constructs the document and places the <!DOCTYPE HTML> on top. this was my mistake. in the original example, it was without it and the issue was easily reproducible on a local PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem was related to the mistake I made in the main application template.

I forgot to place:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

on top of the HTML page. This simple mistake caused the issue. The fix is simple but took several days of debugging! Hopefully, this answer will be useful for somebody.

Comment: This solved it for me. Can you add why this is happening? I don't see it as a requirement on the bootstrap instructions for tooltips.

Comment: finally, after 3 hours of searching, you are a savior